# how to use with_items register.results

Tags: ansible

I'm currently running a command as follows:

```
- name: "1. search directory"
  shell: find /var/ -name "directory"
  register: directoty

- name: "boucle"
  debug:
    msg: "{{item}}"
    with_items: "{{directory.stdout_lines}}"

- name: "2. check existance of file"
  stat:
   path: "{{item}}/file.log"
  with_items: "{{directory.stdout_lines}}"
  register: checkfile

- debug:
   msg: "file name {{item}} exists"
   with_items: {{checkfile.results}}
   when: checkfile.stat.exists
```

when i launch it i have error:

with_items: \"{{checkfile.results}}\"\n      ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}

what can i do to use with_items with stat register

Comment: `We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they start a value` => `with_items: "{{ checkfile.results }}"`

Comment: also with quotes i have the same error

Comment: I doubt it is exactly the same error. I suspect the next error is on your `when` clause, which should be: `when: item.stat.exists`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your last task.

1. Add quotes `"` to the `with_items:` parameter value
2. Use `item` in the `when:` parameter
3. Use consistent spacing in YAML files (i.e. 2 space indentations)

Example below:

```
- name: "2. check existance of file"
  stat:
    path: "{{item}}/file.log"
  with_items: "{{directory.stdout_lines}}"
  register: checkfile

- debug:
    msg: "file name {{item}} exists"
    with_items: "{{checkfile.results}}"
    when: item.stat.exists
```

Comment: i have resolve the issue. i used {{item.item}} in the last debug